# Handling apostrophes in string

Tags: java, string

Suppose that I have a query, something like `SELECT * FROM my_table where name = 'Debbie O'Brian'`. As you may know in SQL Server we just need to put another `'` to make it ignore single quotes. Here is what I like to do automatically.

Briefly, I need to replace all occurrences of `'` with `''` between two enclosing `'`.
Here is what I have so far:

```
String text = "SELECT * FROM my_table where name = 'Debbie O'Brian'";
String[] splitArray = text.split(" '");
for (int i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
    String str = splitArray[i];
    if (str.endsWith("'"))
        str = str + " ";

    // replace all single quotes
    str = str.replace("'", "''");

    // revert last replacement
    str = str.replace("'' ", "' ");

    splitArray[i] = str;
}

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
    builder.append(splitArray[i]).append(" '");
}
System.out.println(builder.substring(0, builder.length() - 2).toString());
```

The problem is that I am relying on existence of a white space before starting `'`. My question is that how can I do this without this pre-assumption?
Any help (even suggestion of an algorithm) is much appreciated. Please mention that there might be more than one single quoted string in query.

EDIT: I am using Hibernate to execute native SQL and getting the whole SQL query as input.

Comment: I doubt this problem can be solved at all in general. Consider this case: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name = 'J'onn '||'J'onzz'` (Yes, the Martian Manhunter.) How would you know what to do? Are the middle apostrophes string terminators or does the name have double pipes in the middle? A better example might be [little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Do you mean now you ask people to pass in the whole SQL, with inappropriate `'` inside, and now you want to sanitize the SQL?  If so, please give up, it cannot be done.  e.g. when you are given a SQL `select * from a where b='x' or c='y'`, it can also be interpret as b=something for which something means `x' or c='y`.  You can never make an appropriate sanitization in such case.  Consider designing your component to take in SQL plus the parameters to be used (You can also do setParameter in Hibernate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, as I mentioned above, my problem was not SQL injection. What I was after, at this point seems to be impossible unless I implement a SQL parser which is obviously too much for the requirement. So I am going to stick with my pre-assumption and give up trying to fix the wrong input as two people mentioned in comments.

Thank everybody for your answers.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to handle single quotes and other special characters in an SQL query is by using Parametrized Queries. It is also more secure. I would recommend doing a search on 'SQL Injection'. That will teach you how to protect against and handle the single quotes in your query.

Answer (score 4):

If you use JDBC use

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM my_table where name = ?")
ps.setString(1, name);
```

Comment: I am getting the whole query from user and supposed to return the result. So this can't be my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Hibernate, similar to what @B.O.B said use parameterised queries:

```
    String queryString = "SELECT * FROM my_table where name = :name";
    Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery(queryString);
    query.setString("name", name);
```